# How to change the logo on the HP MP9 back to the default HP boot up logo?

Tags: windows-10, hp, splash

We purchased this HP MP9 PC from our mother chapter, now, we cut out ties to them, however their logo was still embedded on the PC during boot/start up splash screen.

It supposed to show the HP logo, but they changed it to use their logo.

We did the “No GUI boot” method but did not work. We formatted the PC and changed the HDD too. But the logo did not change.

Is there any other way?

Comment: You mean the bios splash screen?? Or the Windows startup screen?

Answer (score 0):

### The custom logo is in the BIOS/EFI data.

Look at [this page on HP’s official site](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01646879) for info on how to change it in the BIOS. Seems like if you start it up and get into the BIOS you can disable the custom logo there.

Based on the instructions on that page, this is what I believe you need to do to disable the custom logo.

1. Reboot the computer, and press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to enter **Setup**.
2. Select **System Configuration**, and then select **Boot Options**.
3. Select **Custom Logo**, and then select **Disabled**.
4. Save the changes, and exit **Setup**.

If that goes as expected you can boot up and see the original HP logo.